# Programmatically checking checkbox in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Datagridview with first column as checkbox.I have created the checkboxcolumn at design itself.While updating the gridview according to the entries from database, I have to check and uncheck the checkbox programatically not all at a time but only a specific row.Please tell me how can I update check boxes programmatically.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the data from database directly to checkbox column if it is bit type in DB.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

(row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn.Index] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).value = false;

Answer (score 0):

During bind data you need to check it manually if flag is true then set it checked otherwise unchecked as like

set checkbox1.checked=true or false

Answer (score 0):

Check datagrid prerender event, get reference to the checkbox and set value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of databinding use this code

```
CheckBox chkbx= e.Item.FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
```

then you can manipulate chkbx.Checked to true or false based on your values

and similarly it can be used for rest of the checkboxes buttons